# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.data'; '__main__' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь достать `db_session` из папки *data*:

```
from .data import db_session
```

Но выводит ошибку:

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.data'; '__main__' is not a package
> ```

В чём проблема?

Comment: Покажите расположение всех причастных файлов и команду запуска вашей программы

Comment: @andreymal папка data находиться в той же папке, что и файл, в котором я пытаюсь достать db_session

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что точку нужно убрать.

```
from data import db_session
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию, изложите свои предложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1273755/edit)